# How to autosize a set of components in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to resize a set of 3 ToggleButtons enclosed under a constraintlayout.
If I give the size of the layout to be say 101dp and size of each button say 50dp, then android will plot the 1st button completely(0-49dp), then it will plot the 2nd button completely(50-100dp) and then the next button(should have been 101-149dp but will take 51-101dp) considering no margins between buttons. Now, if there is not adequate space then it will start from the point from where it can plot the button completely(like 3rd button). This causes the 3rd button to overlap the 2nd just that the 3rd button will be behind the 2nd.

What I want to do is if there is such a scenario then, it should adjust the size of each button such that all buttons will have the same size.

**Please let me know how I can achieve that.**

**XML or through Java program - any will do.**

### Code For the 3 ToggleButtons made a set

```
`<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/populationButtons"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/populationLabel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/populationValue1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nntscreenbuttons"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal1"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nntscreenbuttontext"
        android:textOff="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal1"
        android:textOn="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/populationValue2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/populationValue2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nntscreenbuttons"
        android:text="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal2"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nntscreenbuttontext"
        android:textOff="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal2"
        android:textOn="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/populationValue1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/populationValue3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/populationValue3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nntscreenbuttons"
        android:text="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal3"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nntscreenbuttontext"
        android:textOff="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal3"
        android:textOn="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_PopuVal3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/populationValue2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a LinearLayout and assign weights to all the ToggleButtons

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: Give me an image of what exactly you want